# Python - "unexpected EOF while parsing"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've watched some videos by Socratica and now I tried stuff out, but it keeps saying  "unexpected EOF while parsing" when I try to save. Here's my code (just to try out stuff)

```
    dir() # Short for "directory"

    print(dir())
    print(dir(__builtins__))

    print(help(pow))

    #pow(x, y [, z])
    pow(2,10) #2^10
    2**10 #2^10
    print(pow(2, 10, 3))

    print(help(hex))
    hex(10)
    #0x start of hexadecimals
    print(0xa)

    print(help(modules))

    import math
    print(dir())
    print(dir(math))

    help(math.radians)
    #180 degrees=pi radians
    math.radians(180)

    #boolean values: True, False
    True
    print(True)

    a=3
    b=5
    print(a == b)
    print(a != b) # ! means not
    print(a > b)
    print(a < b)
    print(type(True))

    #every number except 0 bool-->True
    print(bool(28))
    print(bool(-2.71828))
    print(bool(0))

    #strings True except ""
    print(bool("Hello World"))
    print(bool("   "))
    print(bool("")

    #print(int(True))
    #print(2 + True)
```

btw I made

```
    print(int(True))
```

and

```
    print(2 + True)
```

notes because for some reason it saidd there's a syntax error even though Socratica said that this would say 1 and add 2+1 :/

I use python 3.7

Comment: Missing parenthesis on `print(bool("")`.

Comment: BTW I use IDLE 3.7

Comment: Duplicate of many, many questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E2%80%9Cunexpected+EOF+while+parsing%E2%80%9D

Comment: Oh now I see, thanks

Comment: Um I got another question about hex(10), in the shell it says     >>> hex(12648430)
    '0xc0ffee'

Answer (score 0):

```
...
#strings True except ""
print(bool("Hello World"))
print(bool("   "))
# missing parenthesis in this line -> print(bool("")
print(bool(""))

#print(int(True))
#print(2 + True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Those examples are meant to be tested in a python REPL - Read Eval Print Loop, which is a prompt where you type commands and see the results. You are not supposed to save anything. The lines are not a complete program you should save, just some experimentation commands you should run and try to make sense.

Go to https://www.python.org/downloads/ download python and install it. Then run python

You will see a prompt like this:

```
>>>
```

Then type each command one by one, don't paste all commands. The point is to experiment and see. Try changing the commands and see the results.

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'atexit']

>>> print(dir(__builtins__))
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException',
...
'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'vars', 'zip']
```

etc etc...